# ArcGis 10.2 returning an enum status of EsriLicenseNotLicensed

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c++, visual-studio, arcgis-license-manager

I have an old VS project that was using ArcGis for a map control. I now have 10.2 on my machine. code that I used previously to find & initialize the license no longer works. I know the enums changed I fixed that. But still returns an enumstatus of EsriLicenseNotLicensed. I did find that in 10.xx one should call

```c++
if (ESRI.RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime == null)
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
```

But that is for .NET what do I do for C++?
In my code I call

```c++
esriLicenseStatus enumStatus = esriLicenseNotLicensed;
IAoInitializePtr pLicense ( __uuidof (AoInitialize));
esriLicenseProductCode eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeEngine;

        while( enumStatus != esriLicenseAvailable )
        {
            pLicense->IsProductCodeAvailable ( eProdCode, &enumStatus );

            if ( enumStatus != esriLicenseAvailable )
            {
                if (eProdCode == esriLicenseProductCodeEngine)
                    eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeEngineGeoDB;
                else if (eProdCode == esriLicenseProductCodeEngineGeoDB)
                    eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer;
                else if (eProdCode == esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer)
                    eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeBasic;
                else if (eProdCode == esriLicenseProductCodeBasic)
                    eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeStandard;
                else if (eProdCode == esriLicenseProductCodeStandard)
                    eProdCode = esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
```

later I call

```c++
pLicense->Initialize ( eProdCode, &enumStatus );
```

which also fails with an enumStatus of no license

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.
I had to add in the stafx.h file:

```
/* Engine Version support */
#import "libid:6FCCEDE0-179D-4D12-B586-58C88D26CA78" no_namespace raw_interfaces_only no_implementation rename("esriProductCode", "esriVersionProductCode")
#define ESRI_SET_VERSION(prod) \
{\
  HRESULT hr; \
  VARIANT_BOOL vb; \
  IArcGISVersionPtr ipVersion(__uuidof(VersionManager)); \
  if(!SUCCEEDED(hr = ipVersion->LoadVersion(prod, L"", &vb))) \
    fprintf(stderr, "LoadVersion() failed with code 0x%.8x\n", hr); \
    else if(vb != VARIANT_TRUE) \
    fprintf(stderr, "LoadVersion() failed\n"); \
}
```

Then in the file before I attempted to check out the license I had to add:

```
ESRI_SET_VERSION(esriArcGISEngine);
```

I got this from looking at some C++ samples on ESRI's site, in particular the sample for "Converting a tin to a point shapefile" at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Converting_a_tin_to_a_point_shapefile/000100000nqq000000/

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox